# MSBuild script that errors on unknown property

Tags: msbuild, properties

We've a master build script that is used to build our source code. It has a finite set of expected properties which may be passed into it - Defaults are used for properties that aren't passed in.

Is there a way to display an error when an unexpected property is passed to this script? I'm not sure how to iterate the properties which I'd think would be a necessary function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to retrieve all defined / evaluated properties of the current msbuild process using a custom task. See this SO question and answers for reference: [How to access the MSBuild 's properties list when coding a custom task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772426/how-to-access-the-msbuild-s-properties-list-when-coding-a-custom-task)