# Reference a reserved property from an inline task?

Tags: c#, msbuild

Is it possible to reference one of these properties from an inline task?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I'd like to get the value of `MSBuildThisFile` from the inline C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access *all* of those reserved properties in the same way, but the path of the project happens to be easily accessible as a string via [BuildEngine.ProjectFileOfTaskNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.framework.ibuildengine.projectfileoftasknode.aspx) (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx): inline task code runs as an ITask, and ITask has a BuildEngine property of type IBuildEngine):

```
<![CDATA[
Log.LogMessage(BuildEngine.ProjectFileOfTaskNode);  
]]>
```

For other properties you'll have to resolve to methods like [How to access the MSBuild 's properties list when coding a custom task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772426/how-to-access-the-msbuild-s-properties-list-when-coding-a-custom-task), or pass them a an argument (which is the better solution if you only need a couple of them).

Comment: Thank you and thanks for the documentation reference.  Sorry I missed in the docs that an inline task implements ITask.

Comment: No problem :] But it's interesting to know, also the difference between the different code types.